x.() is not a function
So I have this class inside this class object I instance it, but I can't call its functions. The IDE allows me to call the getPoistionDiagram:
export class NodeW {
  childrenIds: string[];
  diagram?: {
    coordinates: {
      x: number;
      y: number;
    };
  } | null;
  nodeId: string;
  parameters: {
    childrens?: string[];
    name?: string;
    nodeNumber?: string;
    original?: string;
    cases?: any;
    parent?: any;
    extra?: any;
    copyIds?: any;
    copyNames?: any;
  };
  type: NodeType;

  constructor(
    childrenIds: string[],
    nodeId: string,
    parameters: {},
    type: NodeType,
    diagram?: { coordinates: { x: number; y: number } },
  ) {
    this.childrenIds = childrenIds;
    this.diagram = diagram;
    this.nodeId = nodeId;
    this.parameters = parameters;
    this.type = type;
  }

  getPositionDiagram(i: number): { x: number; y: number } {
    return {
      x: !this.diagram ? 20 * 10 : this.diagram.coordinates.x,
      y: !this.diagram ? i * 120 : this.diagram.coordinates.y,
    };
  }
}

export class NodesArray {
  private nodes: NodeW[];
  private createNewNodesService?: CreateNewNodesService;

  constructor(nodes?: NodeW[]) {
    if (nodes && nodes.length > 0) {
      this.nodes = nodes;
    } else {
      this.nodes = DEFAULT_NODE_ARRAY();
    }
  }

  getNodes(): NodeW[] {
    return this.nodes;
  }

  setNodes(nodes: any) {
    this.nodes = nodes;
  }

  getParentNode(nodeId: string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.nodes.length; i++) {
      if (this.nodes[i].childrenIds.includes(nodeId)) {
        return this.nodes[i].nodeId;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}

So when I do:

this.nodes?.getNodes()!.forEach((node: NodeW, i) => {       
node.getPositionDiagram(i) // => .getPoistonDiagram() is not a function  
});

Trying to use the method inside the attribute that i have. It doesn't allow me to acces to the method of the NodeW, also it says is not a typeOf NodeW when i check it.
Is it something related to the froEach()?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] this code to be a [mre]. Right now it's not complete since we don't have declarations for NodeType, ``CreateNewNodesService`, et cetera. And it's also unlikely to be minimal if you just pull in more code to make it complete. The goal is that we can copy and paste your code into our own IDEs and see what you're seeing, clearly and directly. Please review how to make a [mre] and then put it in here as plaintext.

What happens when you step thru the forEach with a debugger? What does node get set to? Is it set to the object you were expecting?

I think, your class NodeW don't have possible to access getNodes, because this is a method inside NodesArray, so, you can't access getPoisitionDiagram. You don't need to access getNode:
this.nodes?.getNodes()!.forEach((node: NodeW, i) => {       
node.getPositionDiagram(i) // => .getPositionDiagram() is not a function  
});

You need:
this.nodes.forEach((node: NodeW, i) => {       
node.getPositionDiagram(i)  
});


this.nodes? is a NodesArray, inside has nodes, that is NodesW. I can't acces to NodesW methds, why?

@MarcPuerto your property this.node, has reference to NodeW, not NodesArray, I wrote you can't access a NodesArray method (getNodes), because you are not instantiated a class NodeArray. Look:
if you declared a new variable with instance of this class (NodeArray), you will have  a possible to access getNodes, but, you are trying to access a property who you attribute a value NodeW, who do not have this method (getNodes). When you write the second example, you don't need to access getNodes, because you have your own nodes inside the property.

No, this.nodes? is an instance of NodeArray. I just didn't put the best name for it. But trust me, this.nodes is instance of NodeArray. Inside Nodearray there is nodes, that is private so I acces with getNodes()

@MarcPuerto can you send your code to github and send the git link?
